# count repeated number and replace elements from last index

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

If the count of number `1` is repeated more than or equal to `12`: replace all elements with `2` after last index of number `1`.
Original array contains 0,1,-1;
I tried using below it works, if there is any simpler solution please suggest and help with link to documentation for further reference.

```js
var arr = [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, -1, 0, 1, 0];
var total = arr.reduce((t, i) => i == 1 ? t + i : t, 0);
if (total >= 12) {
  var startingIndex = arr.lastIndexOf(1) + 1;
  var arr = arr.map((e, i) => i >= startingIndex ? 2 : e);
}
console.log(arr);
```

If array is `[0,1,1,1,1,-1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,-1,0,1,0]`
then resulting array should be `[0,1,1,1,1,-1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,-1,0,1, 2]`

If given array is `[-1,1,1,1,1,-1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,-1,0,-1,-1]` 
then resulting array should be`[-1,1,1,1,1,-1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2]`

If given array is `[1,1,1,1,1,-1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,-1,0]`
then resulting array should be `[1,1,1,1,1,-1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,2,2,2]`

Comment: Do you mean most efficient, or simplest?  Also your code doesn't appear to behave correctly.  For example ===12 doesn't account for greater than 12, and is that really the index you want it to fill in starting from?

Comment: updated if condition to total >=12

Comment: I mean most efficient

Answer (score 2):

Use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to find how many, use fill to [fill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill) index starting from last found 1

```js
const oneFill = arr =>
  arr.filter(x=>x===1).length >= 12 ? arr.fill(2,arr.lastIndexOf(1)+1) : arr

const array = [
[0,1,1,1,1,-1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,-1,0,1,0],
[-1,1,1,1,1,-1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,-1,0,-1,-1]
]

for(const arr of array)
console.log(JSON.stringify(
  oneFill(arr)
))
```

optimized version using `.some`, breaks out immediately after finding 12th element

```js
// fills from the 1 found at the 12th instance of 1

const oneFill = arr => {
  let count = 0
  // if equals 1 increment and check if counter reached 12, fill with 2s
  arr.some((x,i)=>x===1 && ++count >= 12 && arr.fill(2,i+1))
  return arr
}

const array = [
[0,1,1,1,1,-1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,-1,0,1,0],
[-1,1,1,1,1,-1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,-1,0,-1,-1]
]

for(const arr of array)
console.log(JSON.stringify(
  oneFill(arr)
))

// I don't know if you want lastIndex, or just the 12th index
// Below is a version that finds the lastIndex

const oneFill2 = arr => {
  let count = 0
  arr.some((x,i)=>x===1 && ++count >= 12) && arr.fill(2,arr.lastIndexOf(1)+1)
  return arr
}

for(const arr of array)
console.log(JSON.stringify(
  oneFill2(arr)
))
```

Comment: Suggestion, there is one more sample array input. You can wrap it in a function and pass both as input. That way, focus is on your code and not input

Answer (score 1):

This is an alternate approach for @[user120242](https://stackoverflow.com/users/120242/user120242) answer. This is more imperative code but uses less amount of iterations.

#### Idea:

- Create 2 variables:

  - `count`: to keep count of valid cases.
  - `index_12`: to hold index of 12th valid case.
- Now loop over the passed array and return value as:

  - If `count` is less than 12 the no processing is required. Return same value/
  - If `count` is 12, check if current index is same as `index_12`. If yes, this is the 12th valid case and return item instead.
  - If `count` is greater than 12 or if its equal to 12 but index is not same as `index_12`, return processed value (*in this case `2`*)

```js
function doSomething(arr) {
  let count = 0;
  let index_12 = null;
  return arr.map((item, index) => {
    count = item === 1 ? count + 1 : count;
    index_12 = !index_12 && count === 12 ? index : index_12;
    return index === index_12 || count < 12 ? item : 2
  })
}

console.log( doSomething([0,1,1,1,1,-1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,-1,0,1,0]).join() );

console.log( doSomething([-1,1,1,1,1,-1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,-1,0,-1,-1]).join() );
```